# Not able to see video from this code?

Tags: javascript, video, html5-video

I tried the following HTML for displaying a video. But I am not able to see video.

Its only loading the video, but not playing it. I'm using '[video.js](http://videojs.com/)' a JavaScript and CSS library which manipulates the video tag for a consistent UI.

If I am missing something please tell me.

Here is my code:

```
<video id="my_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls
        preload="auto" width="640" height="264" poster="my_video_poster.png"
    data-setup="{}" >
        <source src="scroll_index.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
    <source src="scroll_index.webm" type='video/webm'>
</video>
```

I have included above code in body tag and also included references to *video.js* and *video.css* in the head tag.

Comment: As far as I know, html5 video tag exist to help you easily play videos without javascript, what is the function of the video.js file?

Comment: Video.js is a JavaScript and CSS library that makes it easier to work with and build on HTML5 video.Video.js provides a common controls skin built in HTML/CSS, fixes cross-browser inconsistencies, adds additional features like fullscreen and subtitles, manages the fallback to Flash or other playback technologies when HTML5 video isn't supported, and also provides a consistent JavaScript API for interacting with the video.

Comment: i hope, my above comment is clear to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what browser you are testing with, perhaps it doesn't support the html5 video tag, but regarding your comment, I don't think so :)

However, you have neither set the `controls` attribute to make the control panel appear so user can manually start (and control) the video, nor set the `autoplay` attribute so that the video will play as soon as it is ready, so I suggest adding these attributes:

```
<video id="my_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls
       preload="auto" width="640" height="264"   poster="my_video_poster.png"
       autoplay="autoplay" controls="controls" 
       data-setup="{}">
    <source src="scroll_index.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
    <source src="scroll_index.webm" type='video/webm'>
</video>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me... I was running this on Firefox 11. i tried it on chrome, it works fine. I think, i need some plugin's to run this on Firefox.

Comment: controls,autplay are boolean attribute. You dont need a value for it.
Refer this:http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-video-vs-html-video/#fbid=SnhXyDomqf8

Comment: @Jashwant: They must appear to have the value `true`, and they can appear in many forms, including no value, empty string, or their names, refer to this [official link](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/video#HTML_Attributes). I would also recommend to set the them a value of their name so that the document becomes well-formed XHTML document, check out [this](http://blog.whatwg.org/xhtml5-in-a-nutshell).

Comment: but you said that Vicky hasnt set `controls` but actually it did that but was not specifying any value to it :)

Comment: @Jashwant: Aha I see, haven't noticed that, thanks for notifying :)